# Gitlab Regex for Jacoco Coverage

Tags: ruby, regex, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Gitlab allows to [set a regular expression for parsing the coverage from CI jobs](https://gitlab.us/help/user/project/pipelines/settings.md#test-coverage-parsing). We use Jacoco, which gives an output like this:

```
[info] ------- Jacoco Coverage Report --------
[info] 
[info] Lines: 40.38% (>= required 40.0%) covered, 2265 of 3799 missed, OK
[info] Instructions: 41.99% (>= required 40.0%) covered, 10727 of 18493 missed, OK
[info] Branches: 27.79% (>= required 20.0%) covered, 738 of 1022 missed, OK
[info] Methods: 47.16% (>= required 40.0%) covered, 344 of 651 missed, OK
[info] Complexity: 34.74% (>= required 30.0%) covered, 759 of 1163 missed, OK
[info] Class: 58.82% (>= required 50.0%) covered, 49 of 119 missed, OK
```

[Using Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/3hzjgRXxRX), the regex `Lines:\s(\d+\.\d+%)\s\([^)]+\)\scovered` seems to work for the line coverage.

Unfortunately, it does *not* work in Gitlab?

Comment: How did you configure your gradle build to output the report like this? My gradle build only has option to generate xml, csv or html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually does work.

I used the "retry job" button to test different settings and that does *not* work. I assume Gitlab remembers the settings for old jobs.

For reference, you can also [set the regex per job in the YAML file](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#coverage). I got it working with that and then reverted the change, at which point I realized the settings regex still applies.